# In linux man pages, why are some functions listed on both section 2 (sys call) and 3 (libc)

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Take `recvfrom` as an example. This is explained in both these links:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/recvfrom.3p.html

I understand (2) is for sys calls and (3) is for libc functions,
but their header `#include <sys/socket.h>` and function prototypes is the same in both pages.
Are these pages referring to the same function?
If so then why do we need 2 separate pages explaining it? one could link to the other.

Second question I like to ask is; are all the `C Wrappers` defined under (2) functions
of libc (or other libraries)? These aren't the actual sys calls or helper functions provided by the Kernel right? these are all just wrappers which make the sys calls behind the scenes by putting correct values in registers? If so they should have just made a link to the wrappers in section (3), this is so confusing.

Comment: It's not in section 3, it is in section 3p -- which is a special section for POSIX compatible functions, which may be system calls or not.

Comment: It's true that Section 2 man pages document the C interface to the system call, rather than the asm-level interface, because the asm interface is generally defined from the C prototype via standard ABI rules (first argument in such-and-such register, etc) and the C interface is far more widely used.

Comment: But if I include this header `<sys/socket.h>` and call the `recvfrom` function in C, which function will it call, wrapper from (2) or (3) ? i'm guessing the answer is `they are the same function` ?

Comment: A rule of thumb for Section 2 vs 3 is that a C function that does very little except to marshal arguments and call the kernel will be in Section 2.  A function that does substantial work in userspace, even if it also involves a system call (e.g. `printf`) will be in Section 3.

Comment: See my comment above, this is the confusing part, is the wrapper in (2) and (3) referring to the same function essentially defined in libc?

Comment: @Dan: There's only one wrapper, and Section 2 is its primary documentation.  The man page in 3p (again, that's 3p not 3!!!) documents how POSIX says this function is *supposed* to behave.  Section 2 documents how it *actually* behaves under Linux, which may be different (though hopefully compatible).  Section 3p is meant as a convenient resource for programmers trying to write code that is portable to POSIX systems other than Linux, but not as documentation of Linux itself.  Many Linux distributions don't even install the 3p pages by default.

Comment: But the wrapper in section (2), where is it coming from in this example? is it the exact same wrapper form section 3p? or something identical which Linux kernel has defined or something? Any C wrapper defined in (2) is technically defined by a library not the kernel itself right?

Comment: The wrapper documented in Section 2 is contained in the standard C library (most often glibc), and yes, it typically consists of just a few instructions to call the kernel via a machine instruction like `syscall` or `int 0x80` or `svc` or what have you.  There is no wrapper or other C function corresponding to the Section 3p man page.  Again, the 3p man page is only provided for context, to show you how you can expect the function named `recvfrom` to behave on *other* systems.

Comment: Thanks that what I wanted to see. To me, there shoutn't be any C wrapper placed in section (2), this make me think the linux kernel is providing them which is not true, they are all done by 3rd part libraries like libc. Kernel doesn't provide any C wrappers for its sys calls.

Comment: Well, it's a pretty firmly entrenched convention by now.